# How to empty select box when "Please Select" option is chosen

Tags: php, jquery

I have a drop down menu and an empty select box below:

```
<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value='20'>EWYGC - 10-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
    <option value='22'>WDFRK - 11-01-2013 - 10:05</option>
</select> </p> 

$studentSELECT = "";  
$studentSELECT .= '<select name="studenttextarea" id="studentselect" size="6">';
$studentSELECT .= '</select>';
```

The above is in the `addstudent.php` page:

Now what happens is that I have a php code where depending on which assessment is chosen from drop down menu, it runs a query and it displays either a list of students in the select box if rows from the db are found, if no rows are found then it simply displays a message stating that no students were found within an assessment in the select box. The code for this is below which is in the `addedstudents.php` page and is accessed through ajax.

```
$studentnum = $currentstudentstmt->num_rows();   
$studentSELECT = "";     

if($studentnum == 0){
    $studentSELECT .= "<option disabled='disabled' class='red' value=''>No Students currently in this Assessment</option>"; 
} else {   
    while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {
       $studentSELECT .= sprintf("<option disabled='disabled' value='%s'>%s - %s %s</option>", $dbStudentId, $dbStudentAlias, $dbStudentForename, $dbStudentSurname) . PHP_EOL; 
    }
}

echo $studentSELECT;
```

The problem I have is that if the user selects the `Please Select` option, it still displays the message stating no assessments are found, this is because obviously there are no modules in this query so it thinks that as it has no rows display the message. But I don't want this to be dislayed if the `Please Select` option is selected, I just want the select box to just be empty.

Problem is that  even though I tried to use jquery to do this, what happens is the select box goes empty but then comes back with the message milliseconds later.

My question is that if the `Please Select` option is chosen from drop down menu, what is best way to be able to display an empty select box?

Below is attempt of this through jquery:

```
$('#sessionsDrop').change( function(){
    if( $(this).val() == '' ){
        $('#studentselect').val('');                   
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just add DISABLED attribute to the 'Please Select' option?

Comment: are you trying to make it unclickable?

Comment: @ianace No I am not trying to make it unclickable, I just want the select box to be empty if Please Select is chosen.

Comment: if that's the case see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youy have 2 options for this; either filter it on the UI level or on the server level or both.

1.) on the js/jquery level (i will just have to give you a description/pseudocode so that you will be the one interpreting this)

Filter out if the value of the selected is `""` then dont proceed;
Same with @vortextangent's answer only check if `$('#sessionsDrop').val() != ""` should you proceed

2.) on the server side level i'd assume that before you could query your db you have this
`$_POST['session']` or `$_GET['session']` which contains the value of the dropdown

you just have to catch it if `$_POST['session']` or `$_GET['session']` will both be `''` (empty space) and you should not continue with the db query

Answer (score 1):

Just add `disabled` to the markup for the "Please Select" box like so:

```
<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
    <option disabled value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value='20'>EWYGC - 10-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
    <option value='22'>WDFRK - 11-01-2013 - 10:05</option>
</select> </p>
```

Comment: I don't want to disable it, good answer but I don't want it disabled

Comment: Silly question, but why do you need "Please Select" in the dropdown?  Why not make it an empty box and put "Please Select" in a div above it?

Comment: It is a requirement to get the "Please Select" option to be selected and display an empty select box. I don't have choice on that

Comment: That sounds like a bastardization of HTML and a terrible assignment.  I would punch your professor in the face if he asked me to do that

Comment: Its portfolio exercises, Im just stuck on this one, normally I do the disable as you mentioned but in portfolio question it wants me to empty `<select>` when please select option is chosen. I know it seems wierd

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, but it's with jquery...

```
.ajax({
    success: function () {
        //your current code here 
        if ($('#sessionsDrop').val() == "") {
            $('#studentselect').children().remove();
        }
});
```

Comment: Yeah but like I said in my question, I have a php code which it counts number of rows and states that if there are 0 rows from query, then display message, `please select` option will trigger this and thus display the message. I need either jquery to either overwrite this in order to be able to display blank select box OR php to state that if please select option is chosen then select option is blank

Comment: put this in your ajax success callback?